# Prevent photograhing QR code from display

Tags: colors, qr-code

I have been searching, but didn't find any suggestion for the following use case.

At the faculty where I teach, we implemented our own LMS and one of the features is semi-automatic class attendance recording. How does it work? When the professor schedules a class on the platform he is presented with a QR code, which he shows on the projector for all students present in the class to scan. When the students scan it, they are taken to a url that marks them as present on the class. They need to be logged in so that we know which student scanned the code.

The problem we are experiencing is that students can take a photo of the qr code while it is shown and send that photo to their colleagues that are not present. These students can then scan the code from their homes or anywhere around the campus and be marked as present although they are not.

Geo-location wouldn't help much since students can sit in the lounge area and still scan the code that someone from the class sends them.

The question I have is if someone is familiar with a technique that would make the QR code unscannable when it has been photographed. We generate the QR codes in svg format, so maybe there is some color pallete that can be applied and would make cameras unable to photograph it (but they must still be able to scan it :)).

Thanks.

Comment: the camera that is scanning it, is the same camera that would be photographing it. the problem you have can not be solved the way you are trying to solve it.

Comment: Any camera could choose to modify the color palette, you have no control. You probably need to look at a way to make the photographing / sharing unimportant. Security by obscurity never really works.  It could be requirement to activate something physically. Or to scan the (unique) code by each seat immediately after the main. In any case, you can probably never avoid decicated cheaters.

Comment: One of my professors: "We are at university, not in a kindergarten". In short (he attached a lot of thing in it): you must trust the student, or they will behave as children. And your task is to teach, not to manage children.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I totally agree. And that is the first thing that I told them on the first academic class, that they are grown ups now, academic citizens and that they should behave like that. But it seems they always choose the line of least resistance.